# Discount Calculations in Asp Dot Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my gridview i am having sellprice,quantity,discount,netamount. the user enters the quantity and discount and the result should be displayed in the netamount column, i am trying with this code it is not working and the last line i am substracting the value it is giving error please help me to solve the problem..... 
I am writing this code in the Text changed event .....

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        TextBox txtSerAmt = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TxtServiceAmount");
        TextBox txtQuantity = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtQuantity");
        TextBox txtdsAmount = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtdsAmount");
        TextBox TxtNetAmt = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TxtNetAmt");

        if (txtSerAmt != null && txtQuantity != null && txtdsAmount != null)
        {
           TxtNetAmt.Text = (((
           Convert.ToDouble(txtSerAmt.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(txtQuantity.Text))) * Convert.ToDouble(txtdsAmount.Text)/100).ToString();
        }
         txttotal.text = Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text) - Convert.ToDouble(txtNetAmt.Text)
    }
```

Comment: What is `txttotal.text`? Is it one of the columns in the `GridView` or a different `TextBox`? If it is a column, then find the column first. Then check the value of the column , if it is `null`, make it 0 and do your calculation. Could you post your error message for more clarification?

Comment: Closely observe your last line and check the Textboxes name and correct accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
txttotal.text = (Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text) - Convert.ToDouble(txtNetAmt.Text)).ToString()
```

The reason why you are getting the error is txttotal.text is a string type where your calculation returns a number type.So you need to convert to string which is performed by the ToString method

Comment: I am not getting the discount result and in the last line i am trying to do subtractions it is giving error cannot convert int to string.....

Comment: "error cannot convert int to string" , this means you must convert Result To String. assign result to Double Variable And Then Convert Double To String , afterwards assign string to txttotal.text

Comment: How to do substraction,with the above code it is not working,i would appreciate if you share your knowledge with me thanks in advance..!!!

Comment: How to do substraction,with the above code it is not working,i would appreciate if you share your knowledge with me thanks in advance..!!!  It is giving the following error: Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'string'

Comment: Check This is True. Double Result = Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text) - Convert.ToDouble(txtNetAmt.Text); if this true then. txttotal.text = Result.ToString(); then give me your error message. 'Excuse me for my english'

Comment: @Rizwan Please, make sure you have **exactly** same code as Masoomian has written. It must work.

Comment: Thanks Masoomian it is working now thanks for your patience you have shown towards me ........!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Closely observe the last line: there are **txttotal** and **txtTotal**, as well as **txtNetAmt** is mentioned as **TxtNetAmt** in earlier line.

There are some spelling differences.

```
 **txttotal**.text = Convert.ToDouble(**txtTotal**.Text) - Convert.ToDouble(**txtNetAmt**.Text)
```

Comment: **txttotal**.text = Convert.ToDouble(**txtTotal**.Text) - Convert.ToDouble(**TxtNetAmt**.Text)

Comment: @Rizwan do you want to say txttotal and txtTotal are two different text box?

Answer (score 0):

in string to double conversion first you check that the getting value not for null. if null means to putting manually '0' are otherwise, it should rises error and anther one thing after subtracting to most to convert to string like "Masoomian" answer

```
TextBox TxtNetAmt = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TxtNetAmt");

txttotal.text = (Convert.ToDouble(txtTotal.Text) - 
Convert.ToDouble(txtNetAmt.Text)).ToString();
```

and you should check all the FindControl, the control id is correct. and this calculation only do in Rowbound Event